# How can I reference index of array when iterating over NodeList?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iteration, nodelist

I'm trying to iterate over a NodeList to assign each node a color from an array that was declared named 'colors', iterating through the array.

```
const colors = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'indigo', 'violet']; //PLEASE DON'T CHANGE THIS LINE!

//YOU CODE GOES HERE:
const allSpans = document.querySelectorAll('span')

for(let span of allSpans){
    span.style.color = colors[span]
}
```

Expected: each span to have been set from a color in the colors array. (The first span now red, Second orange, etc.)

I ended up doing this to get the objective completed:

```
const colors = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'indigo', 'violet']; //PLEASE DON'T CHANGE THIS LINE!

//YOU CODE GOES HERE:
const allSpans = document.querySelectorAll('span')

let element = 0
for(let span of allSpans){
    span.style.color = colors[element]
    element++
}
```

but I feel like it is sloppy and that there should be a way to do it much like the way that I mentioned in the first block of code. If anyone could help me that would be great so that I can better my understanding of NodeLists

Answer (score 3):

Use a different loop, examples:

`for...in`:

```
const colors = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'indigo', 'violet']; 
const allSpans = document.querySelectorAll('span')

for(const key in allSpans){
    allSpans[key].style.color = colors[key]
}
```

`for`:

```
const colors = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'indigo', 'violet']; 
const allSpans = document.querySelectorAll('span')

for (let i = 0; i < allSpans.length; i += 1) {
  allSpans[i].style.color = colors[i]
}
```

`forEach`:

```
const colors = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'indigo', 'violet']; 
const allSpans = document.querySelectorAll('span')

allSpans.forEach((span, index) => {
  span.style.color = colors[index]
})
```

Comment: Hi Nathan! You can accept the answer by clicking on the check button next to it if it has fully solved your problem. This will guide others.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Array `forEach` method which also provides an index value for each iteration.

```
const allSpans = document.querySelectorAll('span');

Array.from(allSpans).forEach((el,i) => {
  el.style.color = colors[i];    
});
```

Comment: `NodeList` have [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) function implemented, you don't have to create a new array

Comment: @Konrad This way is safer across browsers.

Comment: Every major browser implemented it at least a few years ago